# Did darth plagueis ever make any appearances and if so how similar does he look to Snoke?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, snoke

I've been reading some through some fan theories lately and I really feel like believing the fact the Plagueis somehow avoided his death and made it all the way through to TFA. I've seen some apparent pics of him on google images (yeah, I'm not really trying too hard here) and I can't deny that it looks a fair bit like what Snoke did in the film. I've only seen the film once so I might be completely wrong. Also, what are the chances that they actually are the same person?

Edit: in a way this could be a dupe. But honestly I'm just asking if plagueisis had any previous depictions (canon or not) and whether it could be said that they look convincingly similar.